# Using a dark theme in KDE with Gnome applications (e.g., Firefox)

Tags: gnome, firefox, theme, kde5, plasma5

I prefer the breeze-dark KDE theme. Unfortunately, some gnome apps (such as Firefox) are problematic. In particular, in text input fields in Firefox, one ends up with white text on a white background or dark text on a dark background.

I have:

```
Settings -> colors -> options -> apply colors to non-Qt applications enabled

Settings -> Application Style -> Gnome Application Style (GTK):
    GTK3 Theme: Adwaita-dark
    Icon theme: Adwaita
```

I am not aware of any Adwaita-dark icon theme after extensive searching.

To enable breeze-dark for KDE I have:

```
Settings->Application Style-> Widget Style: Breeze
Settings->Workspace Theme -> Desktop Theme: Breeze Dark
```

It should not be necessary, but I have also installed https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/breeze-dark/.

cat ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini

```
[Settings]
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=true
gtk-button-images=1
gtk-cursor-theme-name=ComixCursors-Opaque-Orange
gtk-fallback-icon-theme=Numix-Circle
gtk-font-name=Liberation Sans Regular 11
gtk-icon-theme-name=Adwaita
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider=1
gtk-theme-name=Adwaita-dark
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS
```

After all of this, Firefox text input fields still have either white text on a white background or dark text on a dark background, making them impossible to read. (Temporary workaround is to highlight the text in a field so I can see what was entered, but that is very clumsy.)

The following question claim this closely related issue was a bug that was fixed:
[KDE - Problem with dark themes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243435/kde-problem-with-dark-themes)

However, I a running Arch Linux with the latest KDE Plasma5 and what appears to be the same issue still exists. However, I notice it mainly in text input fields, not necessarily drop down combo boxes.

Comment: Perhaps try creating a new (empty) user account and changing the settings there? Then you will know with more certainty whether the bug has been fixed.

Comment: I can reproduce the issue on multiple computers and different user accounts, including a new user account.

Comment: Ah nice. Perhaps comment on the bug if nothing else if you have the time?

Comment: @Sparhawk - not sure where to file a bug report. Firefox? Nope. KDE? Nope. Gnome? Nope?

Comment: I just followed the link trail to the question you quote, then the [bug link](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=343369) at KDE. I figure they responded there, so it should be the right place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tested in Plasma 5.12 (Kubuntu 18.04) and 5.14 (18.10 upgraded to backports).

I can select "Breeze Dark" for the GTK themes.

I have `breeze-gtk-theme` installed.

Also, look for other dark themes under *"Settings -> Application Style -> Gnome Application Style (GTK)"* - "Get new themes".

I have seen the Firefox problem when in the past I used dark Kvantum themes, but only in Firefox. Not happening now though.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My experience, GTK+ application theming doesn't work well if it's not gnome session.

You should try the `lxappearance` application while running KDE to apply GTK+ theme or Icon theme. Tested on KDE5 and LXQt.

[image]

I think the Pop icon theme blend well with both dark and light themes.

Comment: Interesting that `lxappearance` works on KDE Plasma5. Thanks for letting me know. Is this the pop icon theme you mentioned? https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pop-icon-theme-git/

Comment: Yes, that's the Pop icon I'm referring.

Comment: `not gnome session`. Don't you mean "not gtk session"? Anyway, in Plasma I have a very good experience with GUI of most gtk applications (Firefox, Chrome, uGet, Disks).

Comment: In what sense `lxappearance` does more for selecting GTK themes than using *Settings -> Application Style -> Gnome Application Style (GTK)* - and then even download new ones under "Get new themes"? If Firefox looks bad with dark themes what can `lxappearence` fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Update for KDE 5.18.3 QT 5.12.5:

[image: System information]

did not have to install `lxappearance` package

GTK2/3 settings are in `System Settings --> Application Style --> Gnome/GTK Application Style`

My issue was with Angry IP Scanner - Breeze GTK style looked like this:

[image: Angry IP Scanner w/ Breeze GTK theme]

Changed to AD-BlueAgave, closed and reloaded.  Now looks like this:

[image: Angry IP Scanner w/ AD-BlueAgave GTK theme]

No additional packages necessary.  Just try a few different GTK themes, and remember to close and re-open the GTK app you're having issues with to view the changes.

Answer (score 1):

In adddition to @AveryFreeman's answer.
If you insist on using the dark variant of Breeze theme for better consistency, it's still possible.
KDE uses multiple tricks to set GTK theme and could do better dealing with dark variants.

In a nutshell you have to fix the following :

1. File `~/.conf/xsettingsd/xsettingdsd.conf`

```
Net/ThemeName "Breeze-Dark"
```

2. Files `~/.config/gtk3.0/settings.ini` and `~/.config/gtk4.0/settings.ini`

```
gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme=true
```

NB.1: This is still an issue In Kubuntu 22.04

NB.2: This will fix GTK+ v2, v3, and v4 applications even launched via `sudo`

NB.3: You'll have to redo it if you change theme configuration via the KDE system settings pannel.